# Hide creation date of a file

Tags: finder, metadata

I've failed to produce a document in time - if I send it, the receiver will be able to see the creation and last modification dates.

This is what happens whenever I download files from the web or an usb stick/hard disk: I'm always able to see these metadata.

So, where are these data stored? In the file? What then if I create a text only file: why am I still able to see the creation date?

How can I hide this information NOT from the Finder but from the document itself?

Thanks!

Comment: which type of document ? MS office Word ? and since they already know you are late how is cheating the date going to help you ?

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://danilo.ariadoss.com/howto-change-date-modified-date-created-mac/

Comment: If not edit the meta data in the associated app.

Comment: @JohnWoods How do you edit meta data ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that just hiding the date is not going to convince anyone, since it is normal to find the dates where they supposed to be.

If there is no date one will be very suspicious.

What you have to do is to **modify the date** so that it looks the way you want it.

First learn where the information is stored.

Lets say you are using MS word documents.

Under File click on properties > statistics (you will see the dates).

This part is fun, but do not screw it up.

Go to your system preferences and change the date that will become your

> original save date

.

Open the document and save it. (that will become your **creation date**)

Now change the system date to the date you should have submitted it or day before.

Again open the document and make some kind of small modification then save it again.

That will become your **modification date**.

Here is a sample I just made (notice the dates are not from today but from what I choose them to be).

[image]

You are done.

Do not open and modify the documents after your have changed your system date to today.

Comment: Very clever. :)